# how do I make the retopology mesh easier to see?

Tags: modeling, retopology

[image]

I'm trying to retopologize in blender. Even when I have the 'In Front' option selected as shown in the screenshot, the retopology mesh is hard to see as parts of it hide behind the highpoly. How do I make the retopology mesh easier to see?

Answer (score 1):

Since the latest versions in the *Viewport Overlays* there's a *Retopology* option that allows to see the mesh:

[image]